# How do you return an ajax response object using Bacon.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frp, bacon.js

The following code from Bacon.js will push the data object returned from the AJAX request into the console.

```
   Bacon.fromPromise($.ajax({ url : requestUrlString })).log()
```

What is not clear, is how to assign the returned data object to a variable, or to do anything with the data object when a response is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per documentation (https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#bacon-frompromise) the `fromPromise` method returns an `EventStream` object, whose `onValue` method you can use to attach a callback for handling the data. But that you can of course do without Bacon.js too. The point of the library is that you can gather, combine, filter and transform data from various sources and separate side-effects from data handling logic.

Comment: Thanks, the example at the end of the paragraph in the link you provided helps to clarify the point.